# display subdocuments with mongodb and jsp?

Tags: jsp, mongodb-java

Mongodb and JSP :

my code :

---

```
DBCursor curseur = table.find();

while (curseur.hasNext()) { 
    DBObject ligne = curseur.next();

    out.println(ligne.get("_id")); 
    out.println(ligne.get("joueur")); 
    out.println(ligne.get("equipes"));
    out.println(ligne.get("matchs"));
}
```

---

the code runs normally but the problem is in the display :

---

```
_id 1  
Joueur  { "nom" : "De Oliveira" , "prenom" : "Denilson"}  
Equipes [ "Sao Paulo FC" , "Bétis Seville" , "Bordeaux"]  
Matchs  [{ "date_m" : "1996" , "stade" : "Morumbi"}, 
         { "date_m" : "1999" , "stade" : "Benito Villamarn"}, 
         { "date_m" : "2005" , "stade" : "Chaban-Delmas"}]
```

---

It's correct but :

1. **How can I know the number of columns?**
2. **How can I access the sub documents?**

I want to display a list of data with this structure (without the braces and brackets):

---

```
id : 1

Joueur : nom : De Oliveira
        prenom : Denilson

Equipes : Sao Paulo FC, Betis Seville, Bordeaux

matchs : date_m : 1996
         stade : Morumbi

         date_m : 1999
         stade : Benito Villamarn

         date_m : 2005
         stade : Chaban-Delmas
```

---

Thank you in advance for your cooperation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want fetch the data inside an inner array of your document you need store it in a `ArrayList` or `List` of java, like this:

```
cursor = document.find(query);
     if(cursor.hasNext()) {
     ArrayList<?> Matchs = (BasicDBList) cursor.next().get("Matchs");
             /* here you can iterate over Matchs arrayList and get his data */
             for(int i=0; i< Matchs.size(); i++){
                   JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                   JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(String.valueOf(Matchs.get(i)));

                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                   JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                   String date_m = jsonObject.get("date_m").getAsString();
                   String stade = jsonObject.get("stade").getAsString();
                }
             }
     }
```

**NOTE:** You need add to you project a jar of google.gson, to deserialize more easily your bson object

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ! but : ArrayList<?> Matchs = (BasicDBList) cursor.next().get("Matchs");

=> Error : BasicDBList cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: are you doing the import of : `import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;` ??

Comment: I imported the package! Now there is no error ! thanks ! but when I run my application => Error : java.lang.NullPointerException !!

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("table_auteur");
 
 DBCursor cur = coll.find();

 
    if(cur.hasNext()) {
        
     ArrayList<?> Matchs = (BasicDBList) cur.next().get("matchs"); ......

Answer (score 0):

The number of "columns" can fetched using dbObject.size().  Subdocuments are just fields backed by other DBObjects so you fetch them the same way as any other field.

Comment: For the number of columns it's ok ! thanx !

but for subdocuments display I don't understand !

I changed code :

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("table_auteur");
 
 
 DBCursor cur = coll.find();

 for (DBObject doc : cur) {
     String desc = (String) doc.get("description_generale");
     out.println(desc);

     DBObject auteur = (BasicDBObject) doc.get("auteurs");
     String nom_auteur = (String) auteur.get("nom");
     out.println(reportName);
 }

=> Error : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject ????

Comment: You're casting to BasicDBObject and not DBObject.  BasicDBList is not a BasicDBObject but *is* a DBObject.

Comment: I'm sorry ! but I don't understand !  BasicDBList auteurs = ((DBObject)) doc.get("matchs");
     String stade = (String) auteurs.get("stade");
     String date_m = (String) auteurs.get("date_m");

Comment: DBObject auteur = (DBObject) doc.get("auteurs");

Comment: I put the new code : DBObject matchs = (DBObject) doc.get("matchs");
     String date_m = (String) matchs.get("date_m");
     String stade = (String) matchs.get("stade");
! Error => BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [stade]